# Check if an Eloquent element is related to another one (with MorphToMany relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have those tables :
- blocks
- bloackables
--reports
--modalities
--reportGroups

Block.php :

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Report::class, 'blockable');
}

public function modalities()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Modality::class, 'blockable');
}

public function reportsGroups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(ReportsGroup::class, 'blockable');
}
```

Report.php :

```
  public function blocks()
  {
    return $this->morphToMany(Block::class, 'blockable');
  }
```

The same type of relationship exists for ReportGroups and Modalities...

Basically I'd like to load a Block instance and then check if the instances of Report, Modality and ReportGroup are related to this block.
The idea is to create an edition form with a checkbox for every Report, Modality or ReportGroup instances).

What are the strategies ? I read the Eloquent documentation but I am still confused...

Best regards,
Take care...

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand you completely:
you have

$reportInstances,$modalityInstances,$reportGroupInstances

and you want to determine who has relation to the current block;
ok, you should load the model 'block' with its relations, and check the relation existance:

```
$blcokWithRelations=Block::with(['reports','modalities','reportsGroups'])->find($block->id):

foreach($reportInstances as $reportInstance)
{
 if($blcokWithRelations->reports->where('id','=',$reportInstance->id)->get->first()!=null)
// this report has relation to the current block
else
// this report doesn't have relation to the current block
}
```

the same goes for the rest of relations